# Approximations in computing pressure force on volume element

Tags: fluid-statics, approximations

I'm trying to derive the formula for the value of the pressure force on an infinitesimal fluid element, with all the approximations usually thrown under the rug (at least in my textbooks) being thoroughly exposed and justified.

Let's consider a cuboïd of dimensions $\delta V=\delta X\delta Y \delta Z$. Pressure is represented by a smooth scalar field P(x,y,z). The central point on the left face (parallel to the $XZ$ plane) of the cuboïd has coordinates ($x_L, y_L, z_L)$.

We can compute the $x$ component of the resultant pressure force exerted on the cube (where the second equality results from Taylor formula and the minus sign is because pressure acts inward on the volume):

$$-F_x = \int [P(x_L + \delta X, y, z) -  P(x_L, y, z) ]dydz \\= \int [\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_L, y, z)\delta X+o(\delta X)] dydz$$

Now, from the intermediate value theorem, we can rewrite this as

$$-F_x = \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_L, y*, z*)\delta X\int dydz + \int o(\delta X) dydz\\
=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_L, y*, z*)\delta V + o(\delta X) \delta Y\delta Z$$

where $(x_L, y*, z*)$ are the coordinates of the point where $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$ takes it's mean value.

Using again Taylor formula again :

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_L, y*, z*) =  \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_L, y_L, z_L) \\+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_L, y_L, z_L)(y*-y_L) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_L, y_L, z_L)(z*-z_L) \\+ \textrm{higher order terms}$$

The two resulting terms containing $(y*-y_L)\delta V$ and $(z*-z_L)\delta V$ and the earlier $o(\delta X) \delta Y\delta Z$ are $o(\delta V)$ when $\delta V \rightarrow 0$, hence we can write in the limit of infinitely small volume :

$$F_x \approx -\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_L, y_L, z_L) \delta V$$

which is of course the habitual formula.

My questions are :

- is the above derivation rigorous ?
- it certainly feels clumsy. Are there more elegant/direct ways to proceed ? in particular, is there a derivation independent of coordinates ?